# How to draw image onto canvas

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, cordova-plugins

I have an image that will be loaded by the user with the cordova camera plugin.

The image is in angular data-binding `{{imgUri}}`

How do I draw it to the canvas element? I want to draw it onto a canvas because I'd like to apply some transformation to the image in the canvas.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage

Comment: i've tried it before. doesnt work with angular data binding ng-src. just displays a blank canvas  @Kaiido

Comment: You have to wait your image has loaded before calling it.